# MYSQL : MySql Import failed error no : 150

Tags: mysql

I have two tables , I am exporting this two table schema and renamed it.  Again I am importing the same into it.

**Script**

```
mysql -uroot  audit --add-drop-table=false --no-data SignInAudit UAAudit > out.sql
mysql -uroot audit -e "RENAME TABLE SignInAudit TO SignInAudit1"
mysql -uroot audit -e "RENAME TABLE UAAudit TO UAAudit1"
#Create the table again.
mysql -uroot audit < out.sql
```

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `SignInAudit` (
  `SID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Uname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IP` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LOGIN_TIME` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB 

CREATE TABLE `UAAudit` (
  `SID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `UserAgent` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SID`),
  CONSTRAINT `UAAudit_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`SID`) REFERENCES `SignInAudit` (`SID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

I got this error `ERROR 1005 (HY000)`. It may be due to "UAAudit" is referencing "SignInAudit".  But , I am exporting in correcting order (SignInAudit , UAAudit).

How can I import the sql?

Comment: Stupid question. When exporting you don't specify a database name, just the table names. Could this lead to an error? Do you have a database and a table with the same name? Or is it a typo?

Comment: @tombom it's typo. I edited my question.

Comment: Can you post the tables schema?! And as far as I know your importation code (the last line) should not have the '-e' parameter, because your dump is loaded with the symbol <, not with the -e. At least it don't worked for me with -e and worked without it... I'm under Ubuntu and MySQL 5.5.2...

Comment: @FelyppOliveira , I posted my schema .